# I want to sort my results array according to ip address

Tags: python-3.x

How can I sort my results array according to the `ip`?

When I print results I get this:

```
[{'abc.example.com': {'hostname': 'abc.example.com', 'ip': '11.123.30.116', 'country': 'Netherlands', 'cname': ''}},      
 {'accountstat.example.com': {'hostname': 'accountstat.example.com', 'ip': '11.123.30.133', 'country': 'Netherlands', 'cname': ''}}, 
 {'ae.example.com': {'hostname': 'ae.example.com', 'ip': '11.123.24.22', 'country': 'Netherlands', 'cname': 'site.example.com'}}]
```

Comment: any sorting method would work on this. You just need a custom comparator which can say which ip address comes before. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look at  [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them ordered by value you can convert them into integers and compare them.

```
def ip_to_int(ip):
  return  int.from_bytes(bytes([int(part) for part in ip.split('.')]), byteorder='big')

data = [{'abc.example.com': {'hostname': 'abc.example.com', 'ip': '11.123.30.116', 'country': 'Netherlands', 'cname': ''}},
        {'accountstat.example.com': {'hostname': 'accountstat.example.com', 'ip': '11.123.30.133', 'country': 'Netherlands', 'cname': ''}}, 
        {'ae.example.com': {'hostname': 'ae.example.com', 'ip': '11.123.24.22', 'country': 'Netherlands', 'cname': 'site.example.com'}}]

sorted(data, key=lambda x: ip_to_int(list(x.values())[0]['ip']))
```

Be aware that this solution works only with the IPv4 and with only one IP per item in the `data` list. If you need also IPv6 support you have to first decide how to sort IPv4 vs IPv6 and then accordingly update the `ip_to_int` function.